# How to have dockerized nginx pick up file change from other container

Tags: docker, nginx

**How can I configure nginx and my client app (ember) to pick up file changes?**

**Edit**:

I'm thinking that to share a volume, I need to specify volumes that have the same path within the docker-compose file.

I have mounted shared volumes (maybe?) between nginx and my frontend application but changes made in the frontend application are not picked up in nginx unless I rebuild the docker containers.  I've read a lot of questions and the solutions boil down to a. share volumes (I've done) b. set serve file off in nginx (it is):

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"

services:
  client:
    build: "./client"
    command: npm start
    env_file:
      - .env-dev
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
      - "35730:35730"
    volumes:
      - /var/www/app/client
      - /var/www/app/client/node_modules
      - .:/client
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    env_file: .env-dev
    volumes:
      - /var/www/app/nginx
    depends_on:
      - client
    networks:
      - clientnet
    ports:
      - "80:80"

networks:
  clientnet:
    driver: bridge
```

`nginx.conf`

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format compression '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                        '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$gzip_ratio"';

    gzip              on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_proxied      any;
    gzip_min_length   500;
    gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_types        text/plain text/xml text/css
                      text/comma-separated-values
                      text/javascript
                      application/x-javascript
                      application/atom+xml;

    upstream client_app {
        server client:4200;
    }

    server {
        sendfile off;
        listen   80;
        root     /var/www/app/client/public;

        # Match frontend client
        location =/ {
            proxy_pass         http://client_app;
        }

        # Match assets
        location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|woff2|woff|ttf)$ {}
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named volumes can be considered on local development. But when in production especially when using Swarm, it's better to use multi-staging builds for inserting your front-end static folder in nginx. Because using volumes will be an anti-pattern for updates **(your changes in front-end will not reflect when you do a `docker pull`)**.

I would also suggest you to use bind mounts when doing coding in local for real-time changes between your files in host and container like:

```
nginx:
    restart: always
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./django/static:/usr/src/app/static
      - ./django/media:/usr/src/app/media
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Docker Swarm? The way to do this simply in a v2.x Compose file is to add a `volumes_from` key to the `nginx` service to load in the volumes declared on `client`. I have not used v3.x Compose files yet, but I think you can do similar things by declaring a named volume to contain your app data, and mounting that named volume in both containers. You can copy the files from your application container to the volume in your container entrypoint script.

Comment: Just building this on development so haven't done Swarm yet.  Although, I was probably going to use that.  Weird that is seems to not work in v3.  I'll try this approach for dev and then figure something else out for production.

Comment: Does not work on v3 because the `volumes_from` keys were deprecated. The correct way to do this in v3/Swarm environments is to use named volumes. Hope it works out!

Comment: Yeah, ok.  I've been playing around with that.  Just wanted to make sure I was on the right track - thanks!